# PrimeNG dropdown is hidden by keyboard on a mobile device

Tags: android, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a normal dropdown that works perfectly on a desktop browser, but when I access it on an Android device, the dropdown is immediately hidden and the virtual keyboard is shown. This doesn't happen on iOS devices.

I think the problem is coming from the dropdown filter. On the pop-up, the filter field gets the focus that's why the virtual keyboard is shown.

To replicate the issue, open this URL in an Android device: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown and then try opening the dropdown with a content filter.

Is there any workaround other than removing the filter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now fixed in the latest version of PrimeNG. See the same link in the posted question.

Comment: It is fixed in PrimeNg 7.1.3